# Search Through a Dropdown Menu and Select Element Via Text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to change the `Statement Type` with `selenium` [on this website](http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=ORTX), from `Annual` to `Quarterly`:

[image: What I want]

I've got the x-path of the "Quarterly" element here:

```
//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li[3]/a
```

...and this is my code:

```
quarterly_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu_A"]')
quarterly_select.click()
quarterly_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li[2]/a')
quarterly_select.click()
```

Now, I know I can just select the third element of the list and be done, but some companies don't report semi-annually, and as such, the "Quarterly" element is the second in the dropdown sometimes, and the third other times.

So, I was thinking that I could just search for the dropdown element that has the text "Quarterly" in it instead, and so this is what I've come up with so far

```
//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li[text()="Quarterly"]/a
```

But this isn't working and throws the following error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li[text()="Quarterly"]/a"}
```

I'm not sure what to do. How can I locate the "Quarterly" element of this dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change

```xml
//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li[text()="Quarterly"]/a
                                           ↑↑
```

to

```xml
//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li/a[text()="Quarterly"]
                       ↑↑
```

...it seems to work just fine. Note that the text "Quarterly" in within an anchor, not a list item:

**Structure of the dropdown menu:**

```html
<li>
  <a>Annual</a> <-- Selected element; initially "Annual", 
                    but changes to whatever item is selected
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Annual</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Semi-annual</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Quarterly</a> <-- What you want to click on. 
                           As you can see, "Quarterly" 
                           is contained within an anchor.
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

That's why you should have `.../li/a[text...]` instead of `.../li/[text...]/a`

[image: demo]

**Full code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=ORTX"
driver.get(url)

quarterly_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu_A"]')
quarterly_select.click()
quarterly_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu_A"]/ul/li/a[text()="Quarterly"]')
quarterly_select.click()
```

Comment: Yea but not all companies report semi-annually so I would then have to create a list for those companies or find another workaround that would be less efficient

Comment: @JPWilson - found a solution; see my edited answer

Comment: The `a` just looks for an anchor (<a> element)...see my further answer edits